# Match query fuzzily to an array of candidates

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in elastic with the following document structure:

```
{
   "questions": [
       "What is your name?",
       "How are you called?",
       "What should I call you?",
       ...
   ],
   "answer": "<answer>"
}
```

I would like to match queries to one of the entries in the `questions` array.

For example the query "What's your name"?

The returning document should be the one with the closest matching entry of `questions` in all the documents in the index.

I have tried:

```
{
   "query": {
      "match": { "questions": { "query": "<question>", "fuzziness": "auto" } },
   }
}
```

But that sometimes returns a "wrong" document, even if the query is one of the entries of `questions` in one of the documents exactly.

I've also tried

```
{
   "query": {
      "match_phrase": { "questions": "<query>" },
   }
}
```

But that doesn't allow fuzziness, and since the queries are human inputs, it's not catching enough cases

And lastly I tried

```
{
   "query": {
      "span_near": [
        { "span_multi": {
           "match": {
             "fuzzy: {
                "questions": { "fuzziness": "auto", "value": "<first word of the query>" },
             }
           }
        },
        { "span_multi": {
           "match": {
             "fuzzy: {
                "questions": { "fuzziness": "auto", "value": "<second word of the query>" },
             }
           }
        },
        ...
     ]
   }
}
```

But that (at least as far as I seem to notice) only matches questions exactly with fuzzy words.

What I would like (at least as far as I understand), is a fuzzy TF-IDF across all entries of `questions`, get the best match and then rank the documents according to the best matches of one of the entries of `questions` (not the entirety of the `questions` array)

I'm a pretty inexperienced novice when it comes to Elastic, so I appreciate any tips and tricks or outright solutions you might have for me, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using stopwords? looks like the field "questions" will always have a lot of who, what, when etc. Maybe you can add a list of stopwords that are the default english stopwords plus all the who(s) and what(s). Use this filter in an analyzer and then search using the match query.

Comment: No, unfortunately that won't be enough. These are just select examples, the actual list is much broader

Comment: You can try out vector based search, please check [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch)